# Medal.tv window moving automatically to my secondary monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have dual monitor setup. Main bigger FHD monitor and secondary HD monitor.

My problem is that any time I launch Medal.tv, its windows is briefly shown on my primary monitor, then suddenly moved and enlarged on my secondary monitor. But ONLY when it's started, not unminimized. If I move it back to my primary, it stays there until it's restarted.

I don't know if it's app's bug or it's because of some of my other programs.
So if anybody has similar issue, please let me know.

Comment: Unlikely to help, but a shot: Have you tried to close the app WHILE it's opened on the desired primary monitor? Since I know Windows likes to save window preferences. Also which one is your primary monitor, maybe an old app will always prefer that?

Comment: @gregg Yes, I used this solution for Discord, but for this one - I mean it opens on the primary, but after it gets focused, it moves to the secondary

Answer (score 1):

most likely a resolution difference between monitors and or the dpi scaling on the app is looking for the (less intrusive) place to park. The apps are always running in windowed mode and it could quite possibly be another program since the mouse is free to roam while the app is up and running.